# CFchart shut down accidently my laptop

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-8, cfchart

In these days, I've got the problem about CFChart in my laptop. Because whenever I run (open) CFChart in my latop, which accidently shut down and come out Blue Screen like memory leaking.

PS: Oracle 10g and CF8 are the same installed in this latop as well.

Comment: are you talking about the java chart builder app?

Comment: Do you have all patches installed on your CF8? I remember there was a memory leak in one of the old versions, but not sure it was something to do with charts.

Comment: By default `<cfchart />` creates a Flash chart. The problem might be Flash Player perhaps? Like others say, ensure you are fully patched across the board.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now, I've found why my laptop is shut down once I run my coding. It's because of the following coding and I've saved as "style.cfm" and include it in my chart file.

```
<cfsavecontent variable="theme">
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<pieChart depth="Double" style="Solid" type="SmallNut" angle="0">
    <dataLabels style="Pattern" placement="outside" autoControl="false" font="Arial-10">
        <![CDATA[
        $(colPercent)
      ]]>
    </dataLabels>
    <legend spacing="0" placement="Right" halign="Right">
        <decoration style="None"/>
    </legend>
    <elements drawOutline="false">
        <morph morph="Grow"/>      
    </elements>

    <table>
        <heatmap isEnabled="false" minLevel="0.0" maxLevel="0.0"/>
    </table>

    <popup background="white" foreground="black"/>            
    <decoration foreColor="#B200B2"/>
    <paint palette="Pastel" paint="plain"/>
</pieChart>
<cfsavecontent>
```

So, I've removed  and saved as xml file. Then, 100% working after rendering it again. I cannot convince why my laptop only shut down once for above coding.